# No property findAll found for type Pairs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I want to create a reactive repository using `ReactiveCrudRepository`

I tried this code:

```
import io.nexo.admin.console.domain.ActivePairs;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Repository
public interface ActivePairsSearchRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<ActivePairs, Long> {
    Flux<ActivePairs> findAll(Specification spec, Pageable pageable);
}
```

But during deployment I get error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract reactor.core.publisher.Flux io.nexo.admin.console.repository.ActivePairsSearchRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property findAll found for type Pairs
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: JPA cannot be made reactive as JPA is blocking by design. So this simply won't work.

Comment: What are the alternative solutions?

Comment: Not using reactive with JPA. It is blocking nonetheless so trying to shoehorn this into a reactive stack only complicates things. But you can always just return a list (just use the regular `findAll` and turn the `List` or `Stream` into a `Flux`, still blocking as all results are being fetched and not in a reactive way).

Comment: Can you show me code example, please how to make this convert?

Comment: Just use the regular `JpaRepostiry` and in the calling code transform the result of the `findAll` call using the `Flux` factory methods.

Answer (score 1):

When you would like to find by **Specification** you should declare in method name such as `Flux<ActivePairs> findBySpecification(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);`